# Clojure accessing enums in Android library

Tags: android, enums, clojure

I'm trying to write Clojure on Android. Using lein-droid.

And I want to access enum attributes in the Android library.

In particular, I'm trying to convert this line to Clojure.

```
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
```

My first attempt was

```
(.setStyle paint Paint/Style/STROKE)
```

which gives me error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: Style.STROKE in class android.graphics.Paint
```

How do I get at this enum value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/f-Es-GKYvH4

I've found that I can import the enum directly with :

```
(:import android.graphics.Paint$Style )
```

and use it with

```
(.setStyle paint Paint$Style/FILL)
```

The $ is the crucial separator.